# How many non-negative integer solutions are there to x+y +z = 30 such that each of x, y, z is divisible by 3

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many non-negative integer solutions are there to x+y+z = 30 such that each of x, y, z is divisible by 3?

It is simple if it does not have to satisfy the divisible by 3 condition. However with that condition in place, I can't seem to figure out how to solve this. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: How many non-negative integer solutions are there to $x+y+z=10$?

Comment: Yes. That's better. Forgot that we can transform variables too.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all divisible by 3, then $\frac{x}{3}$, $\frac{y}{3}$, and $\frac{z}{3}$ are all non-negative integers and $\frac{x}{3} + \frac{y}{3} + \frac{z}{3}=10$.

Can you see where to go from there?